# Documentum multiple repositories in single database

Tags: oracle, schema, documentum

Is there a way to accommodate multiple copies of the Documentum repository in a single database? I was thinking of setting up multiple database schemas to facilitate this and then export/import as needed from one schema to another.

Thanks!

Comment: Multiple copies of the same repository, or different repositories?  Can you describe a use case for this?

Comment: We have multiple environments but are limited to one database. These environments facilitate different development efforts simultaneously. So they would be based off of the same repository which would need to be re-baselined from time to time.

Comment: I think you could do this.  I don't see why multiple schema approach would not work.  However, export/import between schemas may not work depending on what you are trying to move around.  For instance, you wouldn't move document content this way, because it also exists as files on disk.  Certain system IDs will also not match without some special configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You typically would have different docbase names and ids for each environment. If you have that then you can also use different users as repository owner and have no conflict at the database level because each user can have it's own schema.

If you use the same docbase name/id in all environments then users must match and you cannot use the same database.

Also, export/importing at the db level is dangerous and skips steps done by the repository like updating sequences, creating tables, etc.